# writing in a file using command from windows command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, command-line-interface

I am working to install a product on my windows 7 system, i need to search for a line in a text file, inside the component folder by name IRU_install.properties there i have to search for a line licenseType=LICR and need to append a line "licenseAccepted=9" after the line is found in the properties file.I do not want to prompt the user as the installation need to be through Batch script and silent installation process.

Comment: `for /f` Should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `findstr` command to find text within a file. See below for an example:

```
findstr /m "licenseType=LICR" IRU_INSTALL.properties
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Line found!
)
```

This finds the string specified in the file specified. The `/m` switch tells the command to print the filename ONLY if there is a match. use `findstr /?` to learn more.

As for appending text, this can be super difficult in Batch, but it can be done.

See the below code:

```
@ECHO OFF
(
  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (IRU_install.properties) DO (
    ECHO %%A
    IF "%%A" EQU "licenseType=LICR" (
      ECHO licenseAccepted=9
    )
  )
) >output.txt
move /y output.txt IRU_install.properties
```

What this does is it uses the `FOR` command to iterate through the lines in the file and if the current line equals the wanted line, then output the license accepted line to a 'output.txt' file. Then move all the text in that to the `.properties` file.